# How can i get a string and return each time a string from array?

Tags: c#

I have this function :

```
private string offline(string targetDirectory)
        {
            string directory = ""; 
            try
            {
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory,"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
                {
                    directory = dirs[i];
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return directory;

        }
```

For example if targetDirectory is c:\ then i get in the array 14 directories. 
Now i want that each time i call the function offline it will return me once the first string c:\$Recycle.Bin 
Then it will return c:\test
and each time i call the function it will return the next string from the array. 
Since im using a recrusive function and calling this offline function from a recrusive i want it to return each time the next string from the array.

Now as it is now it will return the last directory in the array only and thats it.

How can i do it ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it sounds like you want to implement an iterator, i.e. a method that returns `IEnumerable<string>`. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383573.aspx for an example that comes close to what you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way - use `yield`:

```
IEnumerable<string> offline(string dir)
{
    ...
    ... instead of directory = dirs[i] do
    yield return dirs[i];
}
```

Comment: I agree this is how to do this, though there is something to be said for him just returning the original output of `Directory.GetDirectories` and using that.