# How can i return List of directories instead of url's?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get a string and return each time a string from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058827/how-can-i-get-a-string-and-return-each-time-a-string-from-array)

I have this function :

```
private List<string> getLinks(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document)
        {

            List<string> mainLinks = new List<string>();
            var linkNodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            if (linkNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode link in linkNodes)
                {
                    var href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    if (href.StartsWith("http://") == true || href.StartsWith("https://") == true || href.StartsWith("www") == true) // filter for http 
                    {
                        mainLinks.Add(href);
                    }
                }
            }

            return mainLinks;

        }
```

Its getting one url and return list of url's.
Instead i want that the function will get a directory for example c:\
And it will return me a List of all directories in c:\ 
Not subsirectories just the directories in c:\ in my case it should be a List with a 14 directories.

Meaning in each index in the List a directory.

How can i do it ? Tried with Directory and DirectoryInfo but i just got messed up.

Comment: How is this fundamentally different to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058827/how-can-i-get-a-string-and-return-each-time-a-string-from-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static method `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(string path)` returns

```
An enumerable collection of the full names (including paths) for the directories in the directory specified by path.
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304.aspx)

You can use the methods in the class `Path` to get the name of a directory, e.g. `Path.GetDirectoryName(string path)`. Read the documentation carefully at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx).